# Stokes Polarimetric Measurements

Tags: optics, polarization

In Stokes polarimetry, a method is presented in "The Handbook of Optics", Chp 22 by Chipman under light measuring polarimetry that presents a data reduction equation for finding the 4 Stokes parameters of an incoming beam.  Equation (18) is presented as

$$
P = A·S = a_0S_0 + a_1S_1 + a_2S_2 + a_3S_3
$$

where $A$ represents a vector of 4 polarization measurements, and $S$ is the unknown incident Stokes vector. $A$ consists specifically of

$$a_0 = P_H + P_V $$
$$a_1 = P_H - P_V$$
$$a_2 = P_{45} - P_{135}$$
$$a_3 = P_R - P_L$$

What does P represent as a physical measurement?

Note that we can determine $A$ from experiment as indicated by taking polarization measurements ($P_H$, $P_V$, etc.) using different filters, but this still does not allow us to find the Stokes parameters we seek without $P$.

Comment: This dissertation : http://arizona.openrepository.com/arizona/handle/10150/595816 has a good overview of both Stokes and Mueller measurement schemes in the review section.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with a four-measurement polarimeter, which consists of four separate detectors that each measures a portion of the incoming light.  Because each detector signal is a linear combination of the Stokes parameters, you have four parameters and four detectors, so it turns out that $A$ (your instrument matrix) is a 4x4 matrix that converts $S$ into $P$, which is your total signal.  Then, when you know the Stokes parameters, you can turn that into a degree of linear polarization or whatever.  (See Azzam *et al., J. Opt. Soc*. 1988).

Comment: The problem is that in practice we will have to measure $A$ and $P$ and then do an inverse to get the $S$ we desire.  We measure $A$ using a series of filters and a photodetector on the incoming light, but how do we measure $P$?  How do I get this quantity? If it is the total signal as you say, should I just measure the light with no filters?